# no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Symfony 3 and React

Tags: reactjs, symfony, cors, axios

I am experiencing a major concern. I develop an api with symfony 3. This api is queried on Front side with React. The server used back side (API) is http://127.0.0.1:8000. And the server used on the Front side is http://localhost:3000.

When I call the api from the front, I have two errors:
- 405 Method Not Allowed
- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/email/settings' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by: CORS policy: Response to preflight check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

However, I specified the correct method (patch) and configured the header from the API:

Here is the detailed code:

**API (back with symfony)**

```
    /**
 * @Route("/users/email/settings", methods={"PATCH"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param FlashMessage $flashMessage
 */
public function usersEmailEditAction(Request $request, FlashMessage $flashMessage)
{
    if($request->getContent())
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

        $editUser = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find($user->getId());

        if (!$editUser) {
            return $flashMessage->messageError("USER_NOT_FOUND", 1);
        }

        if (!$data['password']) {
            return $flashMessage->messageError("PASSWORD_NOT_FOUND", 1);
        }

        if (!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return $flashMessage->messageError("INVALID_EMAIL", 1, "format email invalid");
        }

        if (!filter_var($data['confirmEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return $flashMessage->messageError("INVALID_EMAIL", 1, "format email invalid");
        }

        if ($data['email'] != $data['confirmEmail']) {
            return $flashMessage->messageError("NO_MATCHING_EMAIL", 1, "les emails sont différents");
        }

        // on vérifie le mot de passe
        $encoder = $this->get('security.password_encoder');

        $isPasswordValid = $encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $data['password']);

        // Le mot de passe n'est pas correct
        if (!$isPasswordValid) { 
            return $flashMessage->messageError("INCORRECT_PASSWORD", 1);
        }

        $editUser->setEmail($data['email']);
        $editUser->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());

        $em->flush();

        return $flashMessage->messageSuccess("EMAIL_UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY", 0);



    }else {
        return $flashMessage->messageWarning("NOTHING_UPDATED", 2);
    }
}
```

**the return $flashMessage**

```
    public function messageSuccessAction($message, $code, $desc = null)
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode([
        'error' => $code,
        'message' => $message
    ]));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'); 

    return $response;

    //return new JsonResponse(array("error" => $code, "message" => $message));
}

public function messageErrorAction($message, $code, $desc = null)
{
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode([
        'error' => $code,
        'message' => $message
    ]));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'); 

    return $response;

    //return new JsonResponse(array("error" => $code, "message" => $message));
}

public function messageWarningAction($message, $code, $desc = null)
{

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode([
        'error' => $code,
        'message' => $message
    ]));

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'); 

    return $response;
    //return new JsonResponse(array("error" => $code, "message" => $message));
}
```

**Request API from Front (use Axios)**

```
    requestAPI = (myPassword, newEmail, confirmEmail) => {
    axios.patch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/email/settings', {
        crossdomain: true,
        password: myPassword,
        email: newEmail,
        confirmEmail: confirmEmail
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

I also tried without crossdomain, but nothing.

Do you have any idea ? Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the call that gets the `405 Method Not Allowed` by any chance an `OPTIONS` call? Also called a ["preflight request"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

For all your CORS needs you should include the [NelmioCorsBundle](https://packagist.org/packages/nelmio/cors-bundle), it is easily configurable and you don't need to set your own CORS headers.

What happens here is, your browser will check first whether the server understands the CORS protocol with an `OPTIONS` call. But that isn't answered by your application, at least not with the correct CORS headers, so your `PATCH` call is never issued by your browser because of that. The error message even says so. "Response to **preflight check**: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: I tried with this solution "NelmioCorsBundle" but i have the same problem with a different answer: **Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

Comment: Did you configure the bundle to set the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: paths:
        '/':
            max_age: 3600
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['^http:\/\/localhost:3000]']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Origin']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS']

Comment: I specify that I run symfony with server: run.

Comment: So now it is works. here is what i changed in my configuration: `allow_origin: ['*']` and `allow_headers: ['*']`.

Comment: You should consider restricting it more than just allowing anybody to issue cross-origin requests to your app for security purposes, but during the development phase it will work.